# Use jest inside Jest Test Environment

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have created a Jest test environment in which I mock a specific module:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');
const { lumigo } = require('../../src/services/lumigo');

class TestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    jest.mock('../../src/services/lumigo');
    lumigo.trace = jest.fn((func) => func);
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }

  getVmContext() {
    return super.getVmContext();
  }
}

module.exports = TestEnvironment;
```

And I configure my test to use this test environment as follows:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment ./tests/test-environment.js
 */

... rest of the test
```

However when I run my test I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: jest is not defined
```

If at the top of my test environment file I try to add:

```
const jest = require('jest');
```

I get a warning that `Jest is automatically in scope. Do not import "jest", as Jest doesn't export anything` and the test still fails.

How can I use `jest` (for examples invocations to `jest.mock`) inside my test environment?

Comment: You don't need to import jest. You might have a configuration issue here

Comment: Add  const jest = this.jestRequireActual('jest'); after await super.setup(); . If it works for you let me know i will expalin this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to call the mock from within your class. `jest.mock('../../src/services/lumigo');` You may also need to mention this file in your jest config. Possibly in the [`setupFilesAfterEnv` attribute](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array).

By design jest.mock expressions like that one are hoisted and called even before the imports, though conventionally they usually appear below the imports in the file. If you want to prevent this behavior, you can use [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

FWIW in a properly configured jest environment, you will not need to import jest. I am not sure exactly how it works, but once you have configured `jest`, it's available globally.